# AngularJS set checkbox checked, and ionRangeSliders value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to set default values for some inputs, it works fine for all other input, but I'm having problems with the check boxes and the slider.  (setting them to checked when needed)

This is my controller:

```
App.controller('EmailAlertController', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $http, $timeout) 
{
    var ID = $stateParams.ID;

    $http.get('ajax/email_alerts/view_email_alert.php?ID='+ID).then(function (results) 
    {
        $scope.EmailAlert = results.data
    });

});
```

This is view_email_alert.php:

```
$EmailAlerts = array();

if (isset($_GET['ID']) && intval($_GET['ID']) > 0) 
{
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $EmailAlerts = EmailAlerts::getById($ID);
}
echo json_encode($EmailAlerts);
```

With this result:

```
{"ID":"9539","AppRef":"7418","PriceMin":"439900","PriceMax":"789800","Type":"House","SubType":"Detached House","Rooms":"4","Area":"City","SubArea":"Town","Terms":"Fixed Price","SearchGroupName":"name","DTRecv":"2014-12-08 23:02:15.440","DTCreated":"12-08-2014 06:36","Name":"Name Example","Email":"email@email.com","Protection":"Protected"}
```

And my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Terms" id="Terms"  ng-model="EmailAlert.Terms" value="{{EmailAlert.Terms}}" ng-checked="EmailAlert.Terms=='Fixed Price'" ng-true-value="Fixed Price" ng-false-value=""> {{EmailAlert.Terms}} 




var min = $('#PriceRange').val().split(";")[0];
var max = $('#PriceRange').val().split(";")[1];


$("#PriceRange").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1000000,
    from: min,
    to: max,
    type: 'double',
    step: 100,
    prefix: "&pound;",
    prettify: false,
    hasGrid: true
});
```

Comment: Don't set the `value` attribute on `<input>` if you're already using `ng-model`. ngModel will take care of setting `value`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even without the value is not being set to checked